# C++ Remove x byte every x in char

Tags: c++, winapi, byte

Hi for my application i need to remove null byte on a char array evry X bytes like:

```
char a[] = "\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x00\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x00\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x00\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x00\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x00\x0B8\x0B8\x0B8\x00\x00"
```

need to be

```
char a[] = "\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8\xB8";
```

and i need a function without std just WINAPI Thanks

Comment: Your title (Remove x byte every x in char) and your description (i need to remove null byte on a char array) are 2 different cases.  Also your example is very confusing because next to the nul characters (\x00), you also removed the 0's from \x0B8.  '\x00' and "0" are completetly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jerry Coffin describes the idiomatic solution to this general type of problem.

You'll want to scan and modify the array in-place, scanning from left to right, preserving or deleting elements as you go, while keeping track of the source (input) index and the target (output) index. Since this scans each element of the array once, it's an O(*n*) algorithm.

For example:

```
// Remove all '\x00' elements from an array
int remove_zeros(char a[], int len)
{
    int  si;   // Source index
    int  di;   // Destination index

    // Scan the array from left to right, removing '\x00' elements
    di = 0;
    for (si = 0;  si < len;  si++)
    {
        if (a[si] != '\x00')
            a[di++] = a[si];    // Keep/move the element
        // Otherwise skip/remove the element
    }

    return di;   // Resulting length of the modified array
}
```

The `di` index is guaranteed to be no greater than `si` as the loop progresses. The `if` condition can be modified to whatever condition you need for preserving elements within the array.

Note: To be completely pedantic, the indices and length should be type `size_t`, so that arrays of any size can be processed. I used `int` just to keep things simple.

Comment: this is not really what i want, I would choose an interval, remove a selection every X bytes this selection can be anything not necessarily null bytes

Comment: Your question as stated is not very clear, so I gave a very generic answer. You can change the `if` condition in my code to remove/keep any particular char; for example, `a[si] != '\x00' && si % x == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way would be to walk through the array from beginning to end, keeping track of two points: a "input" and an "output". The two will start out the same (the beginning of the array), but every time you encounter a byte you don't want in the result, you'll move the input to the next byte, but leave the output alone. When you encounter a byte you do want to keep, you'll copy from the input point to the output point, then update both of them to point to the next byte.

Comment: Seems like an okay solution in my opinion. O(n) time, O(n) memory (less than double).

Comment: @VictorZamanian: It uses *no* extra memory (except for the input/output pointers/indices themselves). The input and output are both just pointers/indices into the original array, so you're just copying bytes from one part of the input array to another part of the input array.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thankfully I phrased it in such a way that it's still valid. ;-) Thanks for the explanation!